# Web app doing some mysterious redirecting to Login

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a .NET MVC app with OWIN authentication stored in a SQL database.  I'm running it locally at the moment.

I have the Home controller decorated with `[RequireHttps]` and `[AllowAnonymous]`.  The Account controller is decorated with `[RequireHttps]` and `[Authorize]` with the select login actions being decorated with `[AllowAnonymous]`.

The issue I am having is that when I try to go to **Home/Index** or **Home/About** it will go to the proper action, hit my `Return View();` break point, hit a break point in the view itself, and then jump to `Account/Login`.  I don't know how or why this is happening.

If I remove the `[AllowAnonymous]` on the `Home` controller it will not hit the action result at all, redirecting straight to the login page.

There are no allowed users or roles explicitly listed in the web.config.  There is nothing but the main **Home/Index** default route in the `route.config` file.  In the `web.config` the authentication mode is set to **None** and in the modules it is set to remove `FormsAuthentication`.  I compared my `web.config` to a clean slate MVC app and beyond the additions I have made (connection strings, keys, etc) everything looks default.

There is no javascript on the home page.  I also tested this on a completely empty view and it's the same issue.  Right after I return the view it redirects.

Specifically, the very last thing I can catch before the redirect is the `@RenderBody()` in the shared layout file.  It hits that, then redirects.

At one point this wasn't a problem and I can't pinpoint exactly when it broke.

Comment: Are you calling any variants of `Html.RenderAction` or `Html.RenderPartial` in any of the views / layouts?  You may be hitting another controller action in this way that does **not** allow anonymous

Comment: if the last thing before it redirects is the RenderBody, I'd take a long look at that shared layout. I'd also try find and replace all instances of [Authorize] to strip out authentication all together.

Comment: @BrendanGreen I thought that might be it and indeed there is a partial view but I eliminated that as a possibility by removing all of the content from the view page.

Comment: Sorry, from which view page?  Maybe time to let us see the layout and the corresponding views?

Comment: I agree with @BrendanGreen. The only thing that makes sense is that you're calling a child action *somewhere*, and that child action requires authentication. It's obviously allowing you into the main action and attempting to render the view. The only thing that could interrupt this process, at that point, would be the view calling out to another action.